# Protect Hotlink on Varnish

Tags: linux, varnish

I'm using varnish to cache static content such as : image, css, js .... I am trying to prevent hot linking of images on our site. Please help me config on varnish.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I found this example on the varnish web site from a google search for "varnish referrer". https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleAvoidHotlinking